# React.js and Next.js : TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I can't acces state's values with [...state_name,{}].

I can't solve this problem. I'm trying to set this algorithm for dynamic menu. I'm getting values from useFetch method's List action.

I can get values , its working correctly. Its getting values from json server.

```
import {useState } from "react";
import useFetch from "../functions/useFetch";

const MenuCreator = () => {
    const [menu,setMenu] = useState([]);
    const {data} = useFetch('LIST','/menuler');
    const [subMenu,setSubMenu] = useState([]);
    
    for(let i in data) 
    {
        if(data[i].main_menu == null){
            for(let s in data){
                if(data[s].main_menu == data[i].id)
                    setSubMenu([...subMenu,{id:data[s].id,menu_adi:data[s].menu_adi,main_menu:data[s].main_menu,menu_link:data[s].menu_link}]);
            }
            setMenu([...menu,{
                id:data[i].id,
                menu_adi:data[i].menu_adi,
                menu_icon:data[i].menu_icon,
                menu_link:data[i].menu_link,
                subMenus:subMenu
            }]);
            setSubMenu(null);
        }
    }
    console.log(menu);
    return {menu};
}
 
export default MenuCreator;
```

Photo for error :

[error photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xKks.png)

useFetch.js for this solution:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {URL} from '../config/conf';
const useFetch = (type,url) => {
    if(url === undefined)
        url = "/";

    const [data,setData] = useState(null);
    const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error,setError] = useState(null);
    switch(type){
        case "ADD":
                fetch(`${URL+url}`,{
                    method:"POST",
                    headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
                    body:JSON.stringify(data)
                }
                ).then(()=>{
                    setData("success");
                    setLoading(false);
                })
            break;
        case "DELETE":
                fetch(`${URL+url}`,
                {
                    method:"DELETE"
                }).then(()=>{
                    setData("success");
                    setLoading(false);
                })
            break;
        case "UPDATE":
            break;
        case "LIST":
            useEffect(()=>{
                fetch(`${URL}${url}`).then(res=>{
                    if(!res.ok) throw Error("Veriler Getirilirken Bir Hata Oluştu");
                    return res.json();
                }).then(data=>{
                    setData(data);
                    setLoading(false);
                }).catch(err=>{
                    setError(err.message);
                    setLoading(false);
                })
            },[url])
            break;
    }
    
    return {data,loading,error};
}
 
export default useFetch;
```

Comment: You probably need to `setSubMenu([]);` to reset your submenu. That is use an empty array (which is iterable) rather than `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `subMenu` to null at the end of the first iteration, i'm not sure about the logic of it, but setting `subMenu` to empty array instead of null should fix this error, `setSubMenu([])`. Also it's recommended to use prevState to map values to existsing state:

```js
setSubMenu((prevState) => [
  ...prevState,
  { id: 'new element' },
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from  `setSubMenu(null);`. You need to set it to an empty array instead `setSubMenu([]);`, since `null` is not iterable from how you're using it